# Get sentences from transcript file

Tags: python, regex

I have files of transcripts where the format is

> (name 1): (sentence)\n (<-- There can be multiples of this pattern)
>
> (name 2): (sentence)\n (sentence)\n

and so on. I need all of the sentences. So far I have gotten it to work by hard-coding the names in the file, but I need it to be generic.

`utterances = re.findall(r'(?:CALLER: |\nCALLER:\nCRO: |\nCALLER:\nOPERATOR: |\nCALLER:\nRECORDER: |RECORDER: |CRO: |OPERATOR: )(.*?)(?:CALLER: |RECORDER : |CRO: |OPERATOR: |\nCALLER:\n)', raw_calls, re.DOTALL)`

Python 3.6 using re. Or if anyone knows how to do this using spacy, that would be a great help, thanks.

I want to just grab the `\n` after an empty statement, and put it in its own string. And I suppose I will just have to grab the tape information given at the end of this, for example, since I can't think of a way to distinguish if the line is part of someone's speech or not. Also sometimes, there's more than one word between start of line and colon.

Mock data:

```
CRO: How far are you from the World Trade Center, how many blocks, about? Three or four blocks?
63FDNY 911 Calls Transcript - EMS - Part 1 9-11-01
CALLER:
CRO: You're welcome. Thank you.
OPERATOR: Bye.
CRO: Bye.
RECORDER: The preceding portion of tape concludes at 0913 hours, 36 seconds.
This tape will continue on side B.
OPERATOR NEWELL: blah blah.
GUY IN DESK: I speak words!
```

Comment: But what is the output you intend to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead expression that looks for the same pattern of a name at the beginning of a line and is followed by a colon:

```
s = '''CRO: How far are you from the World Trade Center, how many blocks, about? Three or four blocks?
63FDNY 911 Calls Transcript - EMS - Part 1 9-11-01
CALLER:
CRO: You're welcome. Thank you.
OPERATOR: Bye.
CRO: Bye.
RECORDER: The preceding portion of tape concludes at 0913 hours, 36 seconds.
This tape will continue on side B.
OPERATOR NEWELL: blah blah.
GUY IN DESK: I speak words!'''
import re
from pprint import pprint
pprint(re.findall(r'^([^:\n]+):\s*(.*?)(?=^[^:\n]+?:|\Z)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL), width=200)
```

This outputs:

```
[('CRO', 'How far are you from the World Trade Center, how many blocks, about? Three or four blocks?\n63FDNY 911 Calls Transcript - EMS - Part 1 9-11-01\n'),
 ('CALLER', ''),
 ('CRO', "You're welcome. Thank you.\n"),
 ('OPERATOR', 'Bye.\n'),
 ('CRO', 'Bye.\n'),
 ('RECORDER', 'The preceding portion of tape concludes at 0913 hours, 36 seconds.\nThis tape will continue on side B.\n'),
 ('OPERATOR NEWELL', 'blah blah.\n'),
 ('GUY IN DESK', 'I speak words!')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `regular expressions` and nested `for loops` in a list comprehension to grab all the sentences as illustrated in the code below.

```
s ='''(name 1): (sentence1 here)\n (<-- There can be multiples of this pattern)

(name 2): (sentence2 here)\n (sentence3 here)\n'''

[y.strip('()') for x in re.split('\(name \d+\):', s) for y in re.findall('\([^\)]+\)', x)]

>>> ['sentence1 here',
    '<-- There can be multiples of this pattern',
    'sentence2 here',
    'sentence3 here']
```